# Popup message if empty cell is found in a row

Tags: excel, vba, cell, highlight

This particular Excel is to be in a shared folder for team members to fill.

[image]

I want to popup an error message before saving. The requirements are:

1. In a row, the highlighted columns must be filled (error message before save if not filled).
2. Select the empty cell to be filled.
3. If more than one mandatory cell is empty, select the first one.
4. No action for other columns (Non-Highlighted).

[image]

Following is the code I tried. It gives me empty cells in 1st column only. How do I extend it to multiple columns?

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim sourceCol As Integer, rowCount As Integer, currentRow As Integer
    Dim currentRowValue As String

    sourceCol = 1   
    rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, sourceCol).End(xlUp).Row

    For currentRow = 1 To rowCount
        currentRowValue = Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Value
        If IsEmpty(currentRowValue) Or currentRowValue = "" Then
            Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Select
            Exit For 
        End If



End Sub
```

I'm fresher in VBA.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please include your code so we can help. We cannot write the code for you. Please read: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
Dim sourceCol As Integer, rowCount As Integer, currentRow As Integer
    Dim currentRowValue As String

    sourceCol = 1   
    rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, sourceCol).End(xlUp).Row

    
    For currentRow = 1 To rowCount
        currentRowValue = Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Value
        If IsEmpty(currentRowValue) Or currentRowValue = "" Then
            Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Select
            Exit For 
        End If
       End Sub

Comment: Sorry for not adding codes, I tried this code and I'm getting empty cells in only the column 1, Kindly give suggestion to make it work on more than 1 columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish something like what you want using Data Validation. The animated gif below shows how to set it up to ensure that at least 3 characters are entered into column A, and provides a custom message for the user if they enter less than that. Notice what happens when less than 3 characters are entered into cell A4 after that.  There's a lot more you can do with Data Validation, this is just to demonstrate and get you started.

[image]

Comment: While the Answer itself is good and the question is not, it still does not answer the question in any way. As untouched cells do not pop the error (and data validation will never do). Also there is no minimum length limit in the question.

Comment: I could have used a minimum length of 1 instead of 2 to more directly addressed the "must be filled" part of the question.  But, as I wrote, the above demo will "accomplish something like what you want".  Often times those unfamiliar with Excel ask questions in a certain way simply because they don't know Excel's capabilities, and letting them know related capabilities will provide an answer they're satisfied with.

Comment: Quote: *...In a row , the highlighted columns must be filled...*  so how about the user does not select the cell at all and then saves.... how to make data validation pop the error for cases like that?

Comment: Data Validation can "accomplish something like what you want" if the "circle invalid data" option is selected. It all depends on how tied the user is to a particular solution. I agree that they might not feel that Data Validation is suitable.

Comment: it simply does not work... no matter what... it fires only if the cell value changes. and not touching the cell after opening the workbook simply does not trigger it...